# TimeSpan field types in Crystal Reports or Active Reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, activereports

In a report, I have to implement timespan fields (For example duration of an activity). At the end of the report, a summary based on it should be included.
Neither Crystal Reports nor Active Reports support TimeSpan fields. I don't want to use any formula or other workarounds. Simply just show the TimeSpan fields (like 1:45, 45:23, 0:30) and show the summary at the end (like 109:20).

Any suggestion?

Comment: It sounds like you've set up contradictory requirements. (1) Crystal Reports do not support TimeSpan. (2) I want to support TimeSpan. (3) I don't want to use any formula or workarounds. What do you want to use if not a workaround? Do you want a version of Crystal Reports that supports TimeSpan?

Comment: @Raymond: +1. This can be solved fairly easily with Formulas. Farshid, what's the reason for not wanting to do so?

Comment: I am not limited to using Crystal Reports. Read the question again and you will find that I have also mentioned Active Reports.
By the way, since yesterday, I found that active reports could support TimeSpan by some code behind.

@Ryan: Crystal reports has some problems when using formulas in cross-tab reports & my report has a cross tab structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to say for sure without knowing more information such as why you don't want to use formulas and whether this is a TimeSpan data type in SQL Server or it is stored in some other way in the database, or being calculating somehow (e.g. in application code), etc...

Without more information though, a formula is the right way to solve this in ActiveReports as well as Crystal Reports. Since you need a summary, in ActiveReports (where I have the most experience) I'd say the best way to do this is bring in the timespan value as a single numeric value as *number of minutes*. This will allow you to use the normal no-code ActiveReports summarization features as described [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arHOWCreateSummaryReports.html).

Then to format the number into the desired output text use a formula in the DataField property of the TextBox such as: `=Math.Floor(Minutes/60) + ":" + (Minutes % 60)`. More information about using formulas in the DataField property is [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arHOWAddFieldExpressions.html) and [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/104551/ShowPost.aspx).

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my [ElapsedTime()](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/29/crystal-reports-elapsedtime-function/) function; use it with the summary field's Display String formula.

Comment: I don't think it'll satisfy the poster, but it's a good Crystal solution. A custom function is a nice way to handle this.